# Yocto exclude zImage from RootFS

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am not sure why but when I build my image the zImage is containted in `/boot`. This takes up 6.6MB of space I would like to use. No matter what I try I cannot remove this through the bitbake process. In my `local.conf` I have attempted:

```
RRECOMMENDS:${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-base = ""

RDEPENDS_kernel-base = ""
```

and

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS_remove = "kernel-image kernel-devicetree"
```

All answers I have found are from 10+ years ago. Can anyone point me in the correct direction.

I have noticed another large file on my system is `/usr/lib/libicudata.so.68.2` at 28.6 MB. I am attempting to fit my image and a SWUpdate image on my device. If I could get rid of the `zImage` and `libicudata.so.68.2` I would have enough space on my current NAND chip.

Are these two files required to be in the rootsf, if not how can I remove them?

Comment: Do you have a separate `/boot` partition that also has the `zImage`?